# Règles: Verbes pronominaux à l'impératif avec "en"/"y" + forme négative

Tags: grammaire, impératif, inversion

Je sais que `s'en aller` à l'impératif s'emploie de cette manière:

```
Va-t'en!
Allez-vous en?
```

J'ai voulu dire à un ami `rappelle-toi de ça, c'est très important` mais en employant la règle ci-dessus et ça a donné:

```
Rappelle-t'en, c'est très important.
```

Sauf que ça sonne d'autant plus drôle et donc incorrect que je ne connais pas la règle grammaticale en présence du complément **en**.

**Faut-il juste que je m'y habitue ou est-ce vraiment incorrect?**

**Quelle en est la forme négative?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Rappelle-t'en, c'est très important.

est tout à fait correct, aucun problème.

La forme négative serait:

> Ne t'en rappelle pas, ce n'est pas important.

Ou, peut-être plus naturel:

> Pas la peine de t'en rappeler, ce n'est pas important.

En langage parlé, on rencontre parfois (merci jlliagre):

> rappelles-en toi, ...

Par contre:

> Rappelle-toi-z'en, ...

est une forme très relâchée du langage parlé, en tout cas en France, (avec une liaison euphonique "-z-" pour éviter un [hiatus](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_s&page=9NKqpKB1zx8E.html)), que l'on entend bien sûr, mais qui n'est pas acceptable à l'écrit hors effet de style, par exemple dans un dialogue.

Answer (score -3):

La proposition de Frank est correct, mais il est tout aussi correct de dire:

> rappelle-toi s'en, c'est très important.

La forme négative est:

> Ne t'en rappelle pas, ce n'est pas important.

Comment: Je ne vois pas pourquoi cette réponse a été downvotée. Raison? J'upvote. "rappelle-toi s'en" est familier, sans doute incorrect grammaticalement, mais certainement entendu tous les jours.

Comment: @Frank « Rappelle-toi s'en » ou plutôt « rappelle-toi-z'en » est une forme très relâchée du langage parlé mais il est très exagéré de dire qu'il s'agit d'une forme aussi correcte que l'autre. Aucune grammaire ne l'accepte.

Comment: @jlliagre - on pourrait modifier la réponse pour signaler cela - et je suis d'accord avec votre analyse - sans downvoter la réponse. Cette expression est utilisée dans la vie de tous les jours. Je modifierai juste la réponse dans ce sens.

Comment: @Frank C'est à l'auteur de modifier sa réponse. Les modifications faites par un tiers peuvent corriger la forme, mais ne doivent pas modifier le fond.

Comment: @jlliagre - oui, donc, ne downvotons pas, mais signalons dans les commentaires qu'une mise-à-jour serait la bienvenue - ce que nous venons de faire. Sapienz - la balle est dans votre camp.

Comment: @jlliagre - "rappelle-toi s'en" ne vous en déplaise, est très utilisé en francais aussi bien bien à l'écrit qu'à l'oral. Mais porter un jugement sur cette expression en apportant pour seul justificatif: "est une forme très relâchée" me parait léger comme argument. Libre à vous enfin de downvoter.

Comment: @sapienz - je ne suis pas d'accord sur le point que " "rappelle-toi s'en"... est très utilisé en français ... à l'écrit". A l'école, cette tournure n'est pas acceptable ni acceptée à l'écrit. Si on la trouve à l'écrit dans un livre, l'auteur veut probablement l'utiliser pour son style, dans un dialogue. Je vais devoir downvoter :-)

Comment: Je trouve votre (vous 3) discussion bien interessante, mais je veux simplement noter que "Ne t'en rappel/le pas"  etait corrigee par un tiers dans une des 2 reponses, mais pas dans l'autre. Sans vouloir semble trop bete, laquelle est correcte?

Comment: 2 "l" in _rappelle_ est correct. Un seul "l" est une faute d'orthographe certaine. On peut vérifier dans n'importe quel dictionnaire.

Comment: @Frank Thanks, but that really wasn't my point....I was just wondering out loud why one users' answer was deemed deserving of that attention to detail whereas another one's wasn't. (I get that one answer being deserving of an upvote doesn't mean that all answers are, but what I'm wondering about is totally different, IMHO)

Comment: @PapaPoule - just missed it, that's all.

Comment: @PapaPoule Frank's answer which I upvoted is correct and had a typo that I fixed. Sapienz' answer had three typos but the main issue is it is currently very misleading. This is unfortunate as telling that this regional/spoken form exists is an interesting point that deserve to be known.